# mysql database for monthly subscriber maintenance

Tags: mysql

i would like to create mysql database or single table to maintain data for some small sport club. Actually we have to pay monthly fee for cleanup and so and the best would be to keep that data within mysql. I need to store the following data (id, name, address) and for each month the date when fee is payed. What would be the best and easiest solution?

Comment: You pay every month or you pay from a date and then you have free access till a deadline one month later? (I mean, every fee gives one month free access, without other obligations?)

Comment: payment is on monthly base, once per month

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE sport_club_members (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  address VARCHAR(100),
  payment_due_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

This will build you a table.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic would be a two table approach.

One Table for your members in pseudo code (make your own thoughts ;-) not copy&paste them)

```
ID INT auto_increment PrimaryKey
name VARCHAR(100) //maybe store as split name
address TEXT
```

and another for the received payments

```
ID INT auto_increment PK
UID INT ForeignKey to members table
payment_date DATE
amount DOUBLE
```

Then extract the missing payments for a month via any language/program.

This can be expanded with more detail anytime

Answer (score 0):

You should just use phpmyadmin to create your tables. You will need 2 tables:
1. Table club_members with the following fields (member_id, name, address).
2. Table monthly_payments with the following fields (member_id, year, month, date_paid, amount).

Then member_id in table monthly_payments will be a foreign key referencing member_id in table club_members

Comment: thx a lot. I am on the good way to make this working.